# Export windows Environment variables to a file.

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

Can we write a batch file to export all or some environment variables to a file in windos 7?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and also, is your question just if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for "set".

Type "set >> file.txt" into a command window and regard the file it produces.